# How to prove $ |\langle u,v\rangle| \leq \|u\|\|v\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

How to prove $ |\langle u,v\rangle | \leq \|u\|\|v\|$

Note: I have given this many attempts so don't downvote due to lack of effort, refer to edit history for evidence of said effort

Comment: The last second "identity" is wrong

Comment: For an extreme example, use $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(0,1)$.

Comment: Why the 2 downvotes? I am trying to understand...

Comment: @AndréNicolas Very very good call. It seems I had forgotten something as simple as the purpose of magnitude!

Comment: Or more to the point, I was treating $u$ and $v$ as numbers and not vectors.

Comment: @user142198: your bigger mistake is not understanding the sigma operator and how square roots interact with sums. $(\sum x_i)(\sum y_i)\neq\sum x_iy_i$ and $\sqrt{\sum x_i}\neq\sum\sqrt{x_i}$.

Comment: You may want to look up the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality on Wikipedia.

Comment: Even if you were right about equality always holding, that wouldn't make the stated inequality "not true".

Comment: @bof I know that, but the title should and final question should have evidenced what I was getting at.

Comment: I knew what you were "getting at". However, in math it's a good idea to **say what you mean** and **mean what you say** because math is hard, and us readers can easily get confused even if you say everything right, so there's no need to add to our confusion by saying things wrong.

Comment: And where does $w$ come in?

Comment: @bof say what I mean $\times 2$ because $p\rightarrow q =q\rightarrow p$

Comment: @AndréNicolas I may misunderstand this myself, but don't $u,v$ have $n$ elements, and don't they need to be $(u_1^2,u_2^2,\dots,u_n^2)(v_1^2,v_2^2,\dots,v_n^2)$.

Which equals $LHS: |<u,v>|$

I am not sure, but you might be right user142198.

Comment: Not with your steps I will note though.(As pointed out those steps are wrong.)

Also I am almost certain you are making a joke, but I will note that $p \rightarrow q \not \equiv q \rightarrow p$

Comment: The example I was giving was two-dimensional, and the inner product was the usual one. For general inner products, the inequality is called Cauchy-Schwarz, and there is a proof in the article I linked to.

Comment: Duplicate.     http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436559/a-natural-proof-of-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958334/proof-cauchy-schwarz-inequality)

Answer (score 3):

Your $$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n u_i u_i} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n v_i v_i} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 v_i^2}$$ and
$$ \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 v_i^2} = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i$$
are both wrong.

Comment: On reflection they are both silly. Is that the only scenario that is wrong?