# Prove Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I want to prove $|\langle x, y \rangle| \leq \|x\| \, \|y\|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n $. I know there exist tons of proofs for this inequality, but I want to prove it through a specific schematic.

1. We know that the length of a vector is $\geq 0$, hence for an  arbitrary $t \in \mathbb{R}$ it follows that $0 \leq \| tx + y \|$.
2. I think it's possible to rearrange this inequality such that $0 \leq at^2 + bt +c$.
3. Now we can look at the discriminant $b^2 -4ac$ and formulate a new inequality such that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality follows.

Comment: That's proof 9: http://www.uni-miskolc.hu/~matsefi/Octogon/volumes/volume1/article1_19.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proofs of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23522/proofs-of-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality)

Answer (score 4):

Start by squaring your inequality in (1), giving 
$$
  0 \le \|tx+y\|^2 = \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<tx+y,tx+y> =
   t^2\|x\|^2 + 2t\<x,y> + \|y\|^2 
$$
The discriminant is therefore given by 
$$ 4\<x,y>^2 - 4\|x\|^2\|y\|^2 $$
As the discriminant cannot be positive (note that a non-negative quadratic real polynomial has at most one root), we have 
$$ 4\<x,y>^2 - 4\|x\|^2\|y\|^2 \le 0 \iff \<x,y>^2 \le \|x\|^2\|y\|^2. $$
Taking square roots gives Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Thank you! I have two questions. 1) For $\mathbb{R}$ i understand the rearrangement, but for $\mathbb{C}$ this is only sesquilinear, isn't it? Why is it also for $\mathbb{C}$ correct ? 2) Why exactly ist the discriminant not positiv?

Answer (score 0):

[Kuldeep Singh's *Linear Algebra: Step by Step*](https://maths-for-all.co.uk/linear-algebra/)
(2013) proves this at [p 293](https://books.google.com/books?id=OdrDAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA293&lpg=PA293&dq=%22by+the+hint,+expanding+the+given+inner+product%22&source=bl&ots=XGa-y8DMWS&sig=ACfU3U11ThrTiCyFMinUTfyw-nhqJWnaZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjez6zCsunqAhU0kHIEHXnTCNEQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

[image]